# Wrong user of inheritance at wcf service

Tags: .net, wcf, serialization

I get an error as result of

```
<ServiceKnownType(GetType(EmailMessageTemplate))> _
<ServiceKnownType(GetType(SmsMessageTemplate))> _
  <OperationContract()> <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetMessageTemplates(ByVal handlerId As Integer) As Collection(Of MessageTemplate)
        Dim result = New Collection(Of MessageTemplate)

        result = MessageDataAccess.GetMessageTemplates(handlerId)

        Return result
    End Function
```

which I a webmethod of `wcf` service(because I use:

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="VB" Service="MyAppITWS.Service1" %>
```

and I reference to my application as servicereference

result is a collection of `EmailMessageTemplates` and `SmsMessageTemplates`. Here I my dtacontracts:

```
[DataContract]
public class EmailMessageTemplate : MessageTemplate
{
        [DataMember]
        public string EmailSubject { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public EmailFormat EmailFormat { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class EmailMessageTemplate : MessageTemplate
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EmailSubject { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public EmailFormat EmailFormat { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SmsMessageTemplate : MessageTemplate
{
}
```

How can I fix it?

Here is a pretty error:

> {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 1535. Element
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyAppUtils.DataModel.Messaging:MessageTemplate'
>   contains data of the
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyAppUtils.DataModel.Messaging:EmailMessageTemplate'
>   data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps
>   to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'EmailMessageTemplate'
>   to the list of known types - for example, by using the
>   KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known
>   types passed to DataContractSerializer.
>          w System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, String name, String ns, DataContract& dataContract)
>          w System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String
>   name, String ns)
>          w ReadArrayOfMessageTemplateFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString ,
>   XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
>          w System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
>          w System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ReadDataContractValue(DataContract
>   dataContract, XmlReaderDelegator reader)
>          w System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, String name, String ns, DataContract& dataContract)
>          w System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name,
>   String ns)
>          w System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator
>   xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
>          w System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
>          w System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
>          w System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader
>   reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you read the first line of your error message?

> The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'EmailMessageTemplate' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

that is, add the following attribute to your `MessageTemplate` class

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(EmailMessageTemplate)]
public class MessageTemplate 
{

}
```

see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx) for a worked example

Answer (score 2):

KnownType is usually applied to the base type - i.e.

```
[DataContract, KnownType(typeof(MessageTemplate)), ...]
```

(you can also specify the known-types in the `DataContractSerializer` constructor, without requiring attributes)

If the framework class doesn't know about all the derived types, then you need to specify the known types when creating the serializer:

the syntax is

```
[KnownType(typeof(SubClass))] 
public class BaseClass
```

Comment: click on the edited time eg '33 mins ago' to show you the edit history.